# Get date 900 days ago

Tags: lua

I'm working on a thing that calculates that turns a number eg 900 into a human readable date.

I've got turning 365 into 1 year 0 months & 0 days.
But, how do I turn 365 into 20/3/15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua standard library os provides the functions time and date for such things.
But can use other libraries as well. Like wxLua e.g.

First you need the current time:

```
local currentTimeInSeconds = os.time()
```

Then you need to go back in time. Remeber 2016 is a leap year! So instead of 365 you have to go 366 days back.

```
local timeAgo = 366 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Then call os.date() to convert the time in seconds to a date

```
print(os.date("%d/%m/%y", currentTimeInSeconds - timeAgo))
```

Which will give you the output

> 20/03/15

Please refer to the [Lua 5.0 PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) for more info

Answer (score 2):

```
local t = os.date("*t", os.time())
t.day = t.day - 900
local ago = os.time(t)
```

`ago` is the timestamp of the time 900 days ago. You can get the formatted date as you want:

```
print(os.date("%d/%m/%y", ago))
```

Comment: You should subtract 1 year instead of 365 days so Lua will take leap years into account.

Comment: The question body says 365 days instead of 1 year. Anyway, I've used `900` as an example as the question title.